# Unable to view videos - Message: "sorry, video cannot be played"

Tags: video, files, media-player, system-error

I have a strange issue. I have downloaded some WMV files on my Android to watch them while offline. I watched some of them and now all of a sudden I see "sorry, video cannot be played". None of the videos work any more, not even the ones I watched.

How can I fix this? Please don't suggest WMV players. It worked, now it no longer works and I want to fix it. Reboot didn't help either.

Any clues?

(HTC Wildfire S)

Comment: Have you installed an OS upgrade recently?  Downloaded any new video apps?

Comment: No, as far as I know nothing changed

Comment: Though you say "nothing changed", maybe your video player app got a "silent update" (can happen if you have your playstore app configured to allow auto-updates, so you might not have noticed). So it *might* be worth checking with a different app which explicitly states WMV support -- at least you then can tell whether its the app's fault, or your files "got broken".

Comment: You could try to clear the app data of the videoplayer app and see if this works. Although you don't want suggestions for other players: Is this problem tied only to the default player or do other apps also have problems with those wmv files?

Comment: This happened to me a month or so ago. I gave up and used a 3rd party player instead but it would be a real treat if there's actually a fix for this.

Comment: Sometimes, it because you are not downloaded the full video file.The video is 4:15, your done downloaded just 2:45 so it will displayed "sorry,this video cannot being played" at the end of 2:45.
Another cause is the type of your videos sometime are not supported or you have a corrupted video file.Did you have try send the video to another phone and pc and try to view the videos on your pc?

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem with videos that used to play and then simply don't anymore.  It's not your video player or the video format, its something screwy with Android's file system.

Solution:

Download Rescan Media app from Google Play store.  Install and run, but do not enable the auto-close feature; just run it then minimize.  Your files should play now.

Answer (score 2):

! discovered MP4 videos from an external sources sometimes have too high of resolution.  You need a converter (many free versions on-line) to reduce the size to an acceptable size.

Answer (score 1):

Wait for the next update, or download [VLC Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.videolan.vlc.betav7neon) in the meantime.